# Facebook Graph Api search output language

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, localization

Is there is any way to get the search output of the Facebook Graph Api in specific language? I tried to add `&locale=en_EN` parameter, also i tried to add HTTP `Accept-Language` header. It seems that both ways do not work. Is there any workaround for now?

Answer (score 0):

Answer comes a bit late, but it might help someone else with this problem.

In case none of the things you mentioned work, you could use [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/326576/) library (Language detection using character trigrams) to help you determine what language your posts are written in. It is quite lightweight and fast so it shouldn't pose much of an overhead.